# How to Create a QRcode for Wifi Connection using libqrencode?

Tags: c++, c, zxing, qr-code

I am able to generate a `QRCode` for Plain Text using `libQrencode` with the API `QRcode_encodeString()` and Reading using `Zxing Lib APIS`.

Is there anyway I can create `QRCode` for `Wifi Connection` or `File Transfer` Request like http://zxing.appspot.com/generator and On reading the Generated QRCode Wifi gets connected or File Transfer should start.

Answer (score 0):

QRCode is basically transporting data in form of Image.
 Well, it will vary clear with the above line, we need to create the Plain Text with the information needed and Write the Parser to get the individual details needed.
 For Example:
   For a Wifi Network, we need the below Fields of information:
     **SSID**
**PASSWORD**
**NETWORK TYPE**

Append all the info in single text like 
     "SSID:name,PASSWORD:passkey,NETWORKTYPE:type"  (We can use Json rather writing a Custom Parser.

I will post the Complete Code soon.